# Какие способы приостановить программу на время (сек) вы знаете?

Tags: g++, c++, linux

Предлагаю такое:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {  
    double tim;  
    tim = time(0);  
    while(time(0) - tim != 2) { }  
    cout << "hello world"!;  
    while (time(0) - tim != 2) { }  
}
```

Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Нехорошо занимать CPU бестолковыми циклами. Посмотрите на ответ @Kremchik.  Также можно использовать select().

Comment: Кстати, ЗАМЕДЛИТЬ или ПРИОСТАНОВИТЬ?...

Comment: И сделав c помощью while приостановку, вы теряете управление программой.

Comment: Идея(стара как мир): вынести функцию в отдельный поток, коим и управлять. Остается только сделать синхронизацию потоков.

Comment: Приостановить. Простите, не так выразился.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
...
sleep(2);//2 секунды
usleep(1000000);//1 секунда (1.000.000 микросекунд)
```

Необходимо учесть, что проверяя эти функции printf-ом нужно либо закончить принт на `"\n"`, либо установить сразу после принта flush: `fflush(stdout);`, например:

```
printf("1");
fflush(stdout);
sleep(1);
printf(" - 2");
```

Это же касается и cout. Аналог fflush(stdout) - cout.flush();

PS В Windows этого дела нет, но есть замена:

```
#include <windows.h>
Sleep(1000);//1 секунда - 1.000 миллисекунд
```

Comment: sleep тоже убивает управление программой...

Comment: Ну, так используйте потоки.

Comment: Если я правильно понял: есть функция sleep(); которая принимает время в секундах и приостанавливает программу на это время. Так? И она находится в библиотеке unistd.h. Все правильно?

Comment: Илья, да, всё именно так. С оговоркой, что это в Linux. В Windows есть функция Sleep(миллисекунды) в библиотеке windows.h. Для большей точности в Linux используется функция usleep(микросек), например на полсекунды будет 500 тысяч микросекунд.

Comment: А каким образом делается задержка в микросекунды, если минимальный таймер в Linux 10 милисекунд?..

Comment: ArtFeel, троллинг неуместен!

Comment: @dis2008, надеюсь вы не думаете, что это я писал содержимое unistd.h :) В мане написано, что микросекунды и на деле тах. В php тоже есть функция usleep(micros), на Linux-хостингах её успешно используют.

Comment: Да нет) Мне просто интересно, как они это реализовывают)

Comment: Ну тогда мне тоже стало) В фортранском MPI есть функция MPI_Wtime(), если её два раза вызвать, то может получиться аж 2.0E-005 секундная разница. Я сам сталкивался с тем, что в Java System.nanoTime() (в Windows) может в минус уйти, если сравнивать два момента.

Comment: @dis2008, спасибо, Кэп!)) Я про nanoTime().

Comment: Вывод: использование потоков самый выгодный вариант управления выполнением программы.

Comment: @dis2008  Приведите, пожалуйста, пример приостановки выполнения программы  посредством использования потоков. Только, не идеи, а конкретный код. 

Крайне интересно, каков будет его объем и в чем выигрыш, по сравнению с usleep() ?

Comment: Я за него, в Delphi в TThread, есть функции Suspend()(останавливает) и Resume()(возобновляет). Объем немного больше, а выигрыш в том что остаётся возможным управление программой. Так делал в программе поиска дубликатов. В дополнительный поток была выведена функция поиска и сравнения файлов. Из основного потока реализовывалось управление и отображение информации.

Comment: Глядя на метки вопроса я думал, что речь идет о C++/C Linux и простой однопроцессной/однопоточной программе. 

Хотя, конечно, зная pthread_t можно (pthread_kill()) посылать POSIX потоку сигналы SIGSTOP/SIGCONT в определенные моменты времени. Аналогично можно управлять другим процессом, через kill().

А еще (уж извращаться, так извращаться) можно использовать ptrace().

Но, сдается мне, автор вопроса о таком не думал.

Comment: Верно, это я предложил развернуть исполнение программы в несколько потоков.

Answer (score 3):

Каноничный С++ способ - это использование `std::this_thread::sleep_for`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}
```

Начиная с C++14 можно писать

```
using namespace std::literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
```

Comment: Всё же это метод приостановить лишь _однопоточную_ программу.

Answer (score 0):

1. sleep()и delay() - из стандартной си'шной библиотек (не помню из какой именно),
2. Sleep() - WinAPI из windows.h
3. Использовать для задержки циклы for, while. 
    Так же слышал ещё есть функция wait();

Answer (score 0):

sleep()и delay() 
[вот неплохая статейка](http://www.trivialcoding.ru/Programs/Standart-C/delay-sleep.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>    
int main(){

    using namespace std;
        for (float ex = 0; ex <=4; ex=ex+0.10) {
           system("cls");
           cout<<"Exit through 4 second"<<endl;
           cout<<" ";
                     }
          exit(0);

    return 0;

}
```

Как вариант)

Comment: добавь пояснение что именно происходит в коде