# Открытие файла и преобразование в азбуку Морзе

Tags: c++

Надо составить прогу, которая позволяет текст, содержащийся в файле, воспроизвести сигналами азбуки Морзе. При этом текст должен посимвольно выводиться на экран. Предусмотреть возможность плавной регулировки скорости воспроизведения.

Функция для кодирования в морзе есть, а как сделать так, чтобы из файла читал да еще скорость регулировал не знаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void convert (char[50]);

int main(){
    char eng[50];
    cin >> eng;
    convert(eng);
    return 0;
}

void convert (char en[]){
    int eng2;
    eng2 = strlen (en);
    cout << eng2 << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<eng2; i++){
    if (en[i] == ' ')
        cout << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '0')
        cout << "-----" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '1')
        cout << ".----" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '2')
        cout << "..---" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '3')
        cout << "...--" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '4')
        cout << "....-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '5')
        cout << "....." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '6')
        cout << "-...." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '7')
        cout << "--..." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '8')
        cout << "---.." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == '9')
        cout << "----." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'A' || en[i] == 'a')
        cout << ".-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'B' || en[i] == 'b')
        cout << "-..." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'C' || en[i] == 'c')
        cout << "-.-." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'D' || en[i] == 'd')
        cout << "-.." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'E' || en[i] == 'e')
        cout << "." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'F' || en[i] == 'f')
        cout << "..-." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'G' || en[i] == 'g')
        cout << "--." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'H' || en[i] == 'h')
        cout << "...." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'I' || en[i] == 'i')
        cout << ".." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'J' || en[i] == 'j')
        cout << ".---" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'K' || en[i] == 'k')
        cout << "-.-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'L' || en[i] == 'l')
        cout << ".-.." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'M' || en[i] == 'm')
        cout << "--" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'N' || en[i] == 'n')
        cout << "-." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'O' || en[i] == 'o')
        cout << "---" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'P' || en[i] == 'p')
        cout << ".--." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'Q' || en[i] == 'q')
        cout << "--.-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'R' || en[i] == 'r')
        cout << ".-." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'S' || en[i] == 's')
        cout << "..." << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'T' || en[i] == 't')
        cout << "-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'U' || en[i] == 'u')
        cout << "..-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'V' || en[i] == 'v')
        cout << "...-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'W' || en[i] == 'w')
        cout << ".--" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'X' || en[i] == 'x')
        cout << "-..-" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'Y' || en[i] == 'y')
        cout << "-.--" << endl;
    else if (en[i] == 'Z' || en[i] == 'z')
        cout << "--.." << endl;
    else
    {       
    }
}
cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: cat file.txt | ./morze


morze читает символы из stdin


для задержки использовать что-ть вроде sleep(милисекунды) перед выводом на экран

Comment: На этот вопрос можно дать слишком много ответов, либо же качественные ответы будут слишком длинными для данного формата. Пожалуйста, уточните подробности, чтобы сократить количество ответов или выделить проблему, ответ на которую будет занимать пару абзацев.

Answer (score 2):

> Код для шифрования в морзе есть

Такая пачка else if обычно обзывается термином спагетти-код. Стоит заменить на switch, а лучше на преобразование по таблице.

> а как сделать так, чтобы из файла читал

группа сишных операторов fopen/fclose или плюсовой ifstream, в зависимости от того, что вы проходили. Если ни то ни другое то читайте про ifstream. Работа аналогична с cin, за исключением того что нужно вначале указать файл.

> да еще скорость регулировал

В программе объявить константу "величина задержки в миллисекундах", и в итерациях вставлять задержку перед выводом каждого символа.

Comment: Понятно что задрежка нужна, вы ответье как именно ее сделать

Comment: Потрудитесь освоить поисковые системы. Вопрос [даже здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23284/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5) уже задавался